# NodeJs - Imported variable is undefined

Tags: node.js, import, module, export

Consider this code snippet below which is in the *A.js* file.

```
const connection = {};

mongo_cli.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    ...
    connection['con'] = db;
});

module.exports = {
    mongo:{
        connection: connection['con'];
    }
}
```

I do this `const database = require('./A').mongo.connection;` in *B.js*. A and B js files are in the same directory.

Why database variable in B file is undefined ?

Comment: Are you sure mongo connection was successful, can you print value of connection['con'] in "connect" function ?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia mongo connection was successful, Im sure.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `connection['con'] = db` is in the execution context of the `connect` function callback. If you access `connection['con']` from outside you're likely to get undefined. I suggest you to use Mongoose for such implementations. Here is a simple example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = "your_mongodb_url";
const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
connect.then((db) => {
    console.log('Database Connected');
}, (err) => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

U won't get undefined if the connection succeeded.  so for handling that , you can try something like this.

```
const connection = {};
connection['con'] = null;
mongo_cli.connect(url, (err, db) => {
   ...

   connection['con'] = db;
});

module.exports = {
   mongo:{
       connection: connection['con']; // if connection failed then connection['con'] will be null.
   }
}
```

Comment: the value of connection['con'] out of mongo_cli.connect will be null this due of the scope of the variable in the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a callback function:

```
(err, db) => {
    …
    connection['con'] = db;
}
```

It might get executed *after* the code that reads the `database` variable in *B.js.*